# Adding border to RoundedNetworkImageView

Tags: android, border, android-imageview, networkimageview

I am using a RoundedNetworkImageView.I want to add an border of 1 dp to it.If i create a separated drawable and put it as background to RoundedNetworkImageView then it replaces the roundedness of view.How can i update below code to add border to imageview?
Below is the code I am using-

```
public class RoundedNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {
    public CWRoundedNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CWRoundedNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CWRoundedNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float radius = 12.0f;
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can make border through the canvas. and RoundedNetworkImageView have property of border which you can add in your class or can use another third party library

Comment: @Aashvi Glad if u can help me wid code how to make border with canvas as i am fresher

Comment: may be this link will be helpful for you.. go to this link  https://gist.github.com/guilhermearaujo/9955426